# Apache2.4 + Django 3 - No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to configure my first Django + Apache application.

I am using **Django 3.05**, **Python 3.8**, **Ubuntu 16.04** and **Apache 2.4.18**.

I encountered the `No module named 'django'` error.

```
Target WSGI script '/srv/tacdb/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srv/tacdb/mysite/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/srv/tacdb/mysite/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
 from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

If I activate the virtual environment and run the server, it works just fine.

This is my **wsgi.py**:

```
import os

from mysite.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "mysite.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is the apache configuration file:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 
        ServerAdmin 
        ServerAlias 

        DocumentRoot /srv/tacdb

        Alias /static /srv/tacdb/mysite/static

        WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-home=/srv/tacdb/venv  python-path=/srv/tacdb
        WSGIProcessGroup mysite
        WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/tacdb/mysite/wsgi.py

        <Directory /srv/tacdb/mysite>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/tacdb_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/tacdb_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have installed the latest version of **mod_wsgi**.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

I am logged in as root.

The structure of my project is:

```
.
└── tacdb
    ├── manage.py
    ├── mysite
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apache-site2.conf
    │   ├── apache-site.conf
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── static
    │   ├── tacdashboard
    │   ├── templates
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── README.md
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── venv
    │   ├── bin
    │   ├── lib
    │   ├── pyvenv.cfg
    │   └── share
    └── venvapt-get
        ├── bin
        ├── include
        ├── lib
        ├── lib64 -> lib
        └── pyvenv.cfg
```

I have also tried to grant permision to www-data user for the above structure.

Do you have any ideeas on how to tacke this problem?

Do you think that it is still a problem caused by the permision to 'www-data' on the folder structure?

Anything would be awesome!

Please let me know if other information is necessary. :)

Regards,
Alexandru Bran

Comment: you need to install django

Comment: install django preferred way create virtualenv activate then install

Comment: Have you installed all the requirements in the virtualenv that your apache conf is pointing to?

Comment: I have installed all the requirements in the virtual environment. If I activate it and tun the server, it works!

Comment: @ruddra: (venv) root@test-tools:/srv# pip install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in ./tacdb/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in ./tacdb/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref~=3.2 in ./tacdb/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django) (3.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./tacdb/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django) (2019.3)

Comment: @afk: this is how I have installed django. It works as runserver in the virtual environment

Comment: @danish_wani: I am not sure, but i think so. I think the mod_wsgi and it's packages are the packages needed - I have installed them.

Comment: Do you know how I could test the permissions of the apache user? ('www-data')

Comment: @AlexBran okay you have virtualenv and django, show the output of runserver

Comment: now, i get another error. I think I installed some mod_wsgi packages, or have done some configuration of the file:

  File "/srv/tacdb/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/apxs_config.py", line 8, in <module>
    from mod_wsgi_packages.httpd import __file__ as PACKAGES_ROOTDIR
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod_wsgi_packages'

Comment: sorry, it used to work from runserver...

Comment: can you redo the process again

Comment: I have installed everything on a new vm instance. Now the app works from runserver, but still same error on running with apache:
(env) root@test-tools2:/srv/tacdb# python manage.py runserver 0:80
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 13, 2020 - 10:17:35
Django version 3.0.5, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://0:80/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Comment: mod_wsgi (pid=11756): Target WSGI script '/srv/tacdb/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=11756): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srv/tacdb/mysite/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/srv/tacdb/mysite/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
   from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named 'django'

Comment: i have used this command for permisions sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/tacdb

Comment: do you think this may be the issue? the mod_wsgi is not installed...
(env) root@test-tools2:/srv/tacdb# sudo a2enmod mod-wsgi
ERROR: Module mod-wsgi does not exist!

Comment: (env) root@test-tools2:/srv/tacdb# python
Python 3.8.2 (default, Feb 26 2020, 04:23:39)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> print(django.__file__)
/srv/tacdb/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.prefix)
/srv/tacdb/env

Comment: I have updated permisions to Python site-packages (sudo chmod -R 777 /srv/tacdb/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/) and now I get the following error:
access to / denied (filesystem path '/srv/tacdb/mysite') because search permissions are missing o$
[Tue Apr 14 04:51:02.810044 2020] [core:error] [pid 21311:tid 140609184532224] (13)Permission denied: [client 10.150.34.83:54571] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/srv/tacdb/mysite') because search permissions are missing